# Submit form after return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
       //ajax stuff
            success: functtion(data){
                 //do stuff with data, then submit form

                 $('#form').submit(); // <-- this wont submit the form
            }
       });
});
```

How can I submit this form after my ajax call is complete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have a typo here: `functtion`

then try in this way, creating a reference to the form itself, using native `submit()` method available for `form` element

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;

    $.ajax({
    //ajax stuff
        success: function(data){
             ...
             form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. Didnt know that the jquery method didnt actually submitted the form. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the [native `submit` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.submit):

```
document.getElementById("form").submit();
// with jQuery:
$("#form")[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

have a button with id `btnSubmit` and exec the following code on click of the button...

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
      $.ajax({
       //ajax stuff
            success: functtion(data){
                 //do stuff with data, then submit form

                 $('#form').submit(); // <-- this will submit the form
            }
       });
});
```

Comment: You don't submit forms only by clicking buttons - this would change the functionality a lot

Answer (score 1):

To submit it as-is have such code:

```
if ($('#form').length == 1)
    $('#form')[0].submit();
```

(The `.submit()` method of jQuery object is not the `.submit()` method of the DOM element itself)